# PYthon and Appium: how to go to parent element

Tags: python, ios, appium

I am working with `iOS` and `appium` to control my application.

So i have this `element` that i want to jump into its `parent`:

```
elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_ios_predicate('bla bla')
```

This is what i have try:

```
parent = elements[0] .find_element_by_xpath('./..')
```

I also try this:

```
parent = elements[0] .find_element_by_xpath('/..')
```

And in both cases i cannot fine the parent.

Comment: the first instruction will get the layout of the element you're locating and its children, but not its parents, so your attempts to find the parent like that won't work since the root of the elements object is the element you look for. however I can't tell how to get parent using ios predicates.

Answer (score 1):

XPath is a good locator strategy to find an element's parent.

```
parent = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('blabla/parent::*')
```

This will return the element's parent, where *blabla* is the XPath for `element` from your example. More on XPath Axes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).